# Stripe connect and PHP / Magento

Tags: php, magento, stripe-payments

I use Inchoo's extension for connecting Magento and Stripe payment. Inchoo component is simple and it is based on https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php. When I use it for test payments it works as it should be.

But I need stripe connect because of 'application_fee' and I now have problem.

According tutorial stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth I use https://gist.github.com/afeng/3507366

and everything still works great.

According stripe.com/docs/connect/collecting-fees :

We have following code -

```
// Get the credit card details submitted by the form

$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents
  "currency" => "usd",
  "card" => $token,
  "description" => "payinguser@example.com"),
  "application_fee" => 123 // amount in cents
  ),
  **ACCESS_TOKEN** // user's access token from the Stripe Connect flow
);
```

But ACCESS_TOKEN is problem, because I use the one that I get in previous step 'stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth'

and get error:

**OAuth based requests must use card tokens from Stripe.js, but card details were directly provided.**

Why and where I should use Stripe.js? Everything works great until 'ACCESS_TOKEN' is requested and it says :
// user's access token from the Stripe Connect flow - I already have ACCESS_TOKEN

from 
(stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth)
{
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "stripe_publishable_key": PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
  "scope": "read_write",
  "livemode": "false",
  "stripe_user_id": USER_ID,
  "refresh_token": REFRESH_TOKEN,
  **"access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN**
}

problem w

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: @John Conde. Thank you, but Magento is not issue here, Stripe connect is.

Comment: What was the solution to your problem? We just ran into this as well.